# How do i round it to 7.8?

Tags: python

```py
minutes = 9 * 52
    
hours = round(minutes // 60,1 )
    
print(hours)
```

This is my code, but it only prints out `7` when in reality it should be `7.8` hours instead of `7`

I'm new to Python, so please don't hate too much :P

Answer (score 1):

Change your integer division `//` to floating point division `/` before you round.

```
>>> minutes = 9*52
>>> hours = round(minutes/60, 1)
>>> hours
7.8
```

This is what is going on within your `round` function call

```
>>> 468 // 60
7
>>> 468 / 60
7.8
```